# Hibernate Criteria Restriction on Multi-level Join

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have 3 tables. User, AdminDetails and Branch. In user table, there are some users with admin role. Each admin user has a key in AdminDetails table with one to one mapping. All users are mapped with 1 admin using a self-mapping in User table with entity name admin. AdminDetails has a Many-to-one relationship with Branch table.

Bottomline, my mappings looks like this :

> User (Many to One) > User as admin (One to one)> Admin Details (Many to one) > Branch

Now, what I need to do is find all the users which are under a particular branch. For this, I am trying to use hibernate criteria functionality.

**Approach 1**

I tried to add restrictions directly using mapping. Its working for a single level mapping but not more than that. For example:

```
// This is working
Criteria userCriteria=session.createCriteria(User.class);
userCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("admin.id",3));

// This is not
Criteria userCriteria=session.createCriteria(User.class);
userCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("admin.adminDetails.id",3));
```

**Approach 2**

I am creating sub criteria's and trying to apply restrictions on them.

```
Criteria userCriteria=session.createCriteria(User.class);
Criteria adminCriteria=userCriteria.createCriteria("admin");
Criteria adminDetailsCriteria=adminCriteria.createCriteria("adminDetails");
Criteria branchCriteria=adminDetailsCriteria.createCriteria("branch");
branchCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",1));
List<User> users=userCriteria.list();
```

This is throwing error

> No row with the given identifier exists:com.myapp.dao.AdminDetails#3

My best guess is, not all users contain a row in AdminDetails table. Only users with Admin role contains a row there but hibernate is trying to find one row for each user which is causing the above error.

Is there any other way to get the desired results? Or am I doing something wrong?